# How to make cell B decrease each time the target cell A increases?

Tags: excel-formula

Cell A is the sum of Row A and cell B is the sum of Row B. As cell A increases by 1,500, cell B decreases by 5.

None, I'm a noob.

Zero knowledge, I'm a noob.

I am expecting that as cell A increases by 1,500, cell B decreases by 5.

Like (Row A) 2000 + 1203 = (Cell A) 3203. (Row B) 50 + 15 = (Cell B) 65. Cell B detects that Cell A could be divided by 1500 (whole number only).

Then Cell B becomes 60.

Comment: Could you actually clarify what logic you have in mind ? Why reduce ```cell B``` by ```5```, when ```cell A``` could be divided by ```1500``` (which it actually cannot, it will bring 203 remainder as per your example)

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I'm doing some editing in a book and there's an agreement of per 1500 words, it'll be 5USD for example. 
Row A is the number of words that I edited. For example chapter 1 = 2000 words, then chapter 2 = 1203 words. so Cell A is equals to 3203. 
Row B is the amount that person paid me. Pay 5, pay 10. So Cell B becomes 15, the sum of Row B. 
In this example Cell B decreases by 10, since Cell A is 3203, which could be divided by 1500 twice. And then it goes on as I numbers on Row A and Row B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `cellA` with the actual cell number (i.e. A28)

```
=65-(5*FLOOR(cellA/1500,1))
```

The `FLOOR(a,b)` function will round down `a` to the nearest `b`.

Comment: the 5* multiplies the result by 5. So when I did that it gives me 7500. I tried removing it and then it becomes 1500.

Comment: @MarkAnthonyGalvez what became 7500? Cell B?

Comment: @MarkAnthonyGalvez ah I see what I did wrong, see the edit.

Comment: There we go! That's awesome! Thank you very much!!! That's what I've looking for. =CellB-(5*FLOOR(CellA/1500,1))

Comment: @MarkAnthonyGalvez you’re very welcome, have a nice day!

Comment: you have a wonderful day!